# How do you get this child Div to float to the bottom of the parent Div?

Tags: html, css

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRT2Q.png)

I tried a lot of CSS tricks to get the .booknetic_appointment_container_footer to float to the bottom of #booknetic_theme_5 with no success. The closest I got was hardcoding padding but that messes up the mobile view.

I tried min-height rules and width auto rules with no success. Could anyone take a closer look and advise me on how to get this Div to float to the bottom?

URL: https://windsorproclean.com/

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would to use the margin-top: auto and height: 100%; trick of a flexbox.

Give the parent class (booknetic_appointment_container) the attributes `height: unset; display: flex; flex-direction: column;`
and give the item you want to move (booknetic_appointment_container_footer) the `margin-top: auto;` attribute.

This should make the container take all availible space and push the last item to the bottom. check that your not setting the margins of any of the items in the container to anything if it does not work.

---

You could also unset the `height 100%` of the parent and give the child `position: absolute; bottom: 0` but I think flex-box's are more elegant